# Проверка подключение к MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Как в коде проверить подключение к серверу MongoDB из кода C#?

Когда я хочу вставить данные или забрать их из *MongoDB*, а сервер не запущен, то выполнение программы просто зависает.

А как это предотвратить - не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверить подключение к **MongoDB-серверу** можно с помощью вот такого кода:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckMongoConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            var databases = _client.ListDatabasesAsync().Result;
            await databases.MoveNextAsync();
            return _client.Cluster.Description.State == ClusterState.Connected;
        }
        catch (Exception mce)
        {
            await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync(mce.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Можно аналогично этому коду написать синхронный вариант проверки, но кому он нужен?

Желательно создать *MongoClient* с такими настройками, чтобы проверка при отключенном сервере длилась ~5-6 секунд:

```
_clientSettings = new MongoClientSettings
{
    Server = _mongoUrl.Server,
    ServerSelectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};
```

*ServerSelectionTimeout* по умолчанию стоит в что-то около 30+ секунд. Так отклик будет гораздо быстрее. Но, исходите из своих нужд.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод [Ping](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.8/html/4df96e2d-3273-1075-23df-6baea97942c3.htm) у `MongoClient`

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();

try
{
    server.Ping();
}
catch(Exception)
{
    // сервер недоступен
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835833/how-to-check-connection-to-mongodb)

Comment: Это я видел, но, по моему это уже *deprecated*, а во вторых, не понятно что дальше делать. Он бы хоть возвращал **bool**.

Comment: @Ep1demic, а если `server.Ping();` завернуть в `try/catch`?)

Comment: почему то мне кажется, что это не поможет)

Comment: а у меня из-за отсутствия MongoDB строка `try { server.Ping(); } catch(Exception){}` вываливается в Exception `Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:27017` и следовательно если сервер запущен то Exception не будет

Comment: хотя даже у метода написано `Checks whether the server is alive (throws an exception if not). `, если сервер доступен то ошибки не будет, если недоступен получите exception

Comment: Сейчас испробуем =)

Comment: @Ep1demic таки шо?)

Comment: таки наконец-то отписал =)